# Binary Search in Python: correct slicing

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Please, help me unterstand the silly question about how binary sort algorithm's works.
So, lets take input array of `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 20]` where i'm searching for index of 6 value (see the code).
As I take it should work this way:

1. First of all we take the pivot(middle) point of (end-start)/2=7 as of index=3
2. After the first iteration we got array's slice of `[4, 5, 6]` where we searching the mid point again. With result of index=1 and value = 5.
3. After second iteration we get the only array of 6, which meets the basic condition and we getting correct result.

To prove my assumption I added an output of the cutted array I should get at the second and third step.
But surprisingly it was `[4, 5]` on the 2nd and [] on the third step in opposite to `[4,5,6]` and `[6]` I expected?

Relating to slicing documentation `a[start:stop]  # items start through stop-1`, so the last one isn't included.

But how homes, I'm getting the correct result assuming i'm working with `[4,5,6]` and `[6]` in opposite to incorrect output?

**The code is:**

```
def binarySearch(arr, start, end, x):
  print('the input array is: ' + str(arr[start:end]))  
  if end>=start:
    mid_idx=(start+end)//2
    print('mid index is: ' + str(mid_idx))
    if arr[mid_idx]==x:
      return mid_idx
    elif arr[mid_idx]>x:
      return binarySearch(arr,start,mid_idx-1, x)
    else:
      return binarySearch(arr,mid_idx+1,end, x)
  else:
    return None

arr=[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 20]
res=binarySearch(arr, 0, len(arr),6)
print(res)
```

**The output is:**

```
the input array is: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 20]
mid index is: 3
the input array is: [4, 5]
mid index is: 1
the input array is: []
mid index is: 2
2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is good that you are surprised, because the code is not correct. It mixes two ways to interpret the `end` argument. Some implementations will treat `end` as *included* in the range to consider, while others treat `end` as the index *after* the intended range (this way is how slices/ranges are defined in Python).

The mix in your code can be seen here:

- The calling code assumes the `end` argument as *after* the range
- Your debugging `print` assumes the `end` argument as *after* the range
- The first ("left") recursive call assumes the `end` argument is *inclusive*
- The `if` condition assumes the `end` argument is *inclusive*.

You obviously cannot mix the two approaches and must make changes to make it consistent.

So either (*excluding*):

```
def binarySearch(arr, start, end, x):
  print('the input array is: ' + str(arr[start:end]))  
  if end>start:
    mid_idx=(start+end)//2
    print('mid index is: ' + str(mid_idx))
    if arr[mid_idx]==x:
      return mid_idx
    elif arr[mid_idx]>x:
      return binarySearch(arr,start,mid_idx, x)
    else:
      return binarySearch(arr,mid_idx+1,end, x)
  else:
    return None

arr=[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 20]
res=binarySearch(arr, 0, len(arr),6)
print(res)
```

Or (*including*):

```
def binarySearch(arr, start, end, x):
  print('the input array is: ' + str(arr[start:end+1]))  
  if end>=start:
    mid_idx=(start+end)//2
    print('mid index is: ' + str(mid_idx))
    if arr[mid_idx]==x:
      return mid_idx
    elif arr[mid_idx]>x:
      return binarySearch(arr,start,mid_idx-1, x)
    else:
      return binarySearch(arr,mid_idx+1,end, x)
  else:
    return None

arr=[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 20]
res=binarySearch(arr, 0, len(arr)-1,6)
print(res)
```

Comment: And that's why it's a good idea to consciously decide (maybe even write down) what exactly the function parameters mean, before even starting to implement the function.